# TypeScript decorators naming convention

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions, typescript-decorator

I have a decorator that attaches error handler to a given function. The decorator accepts a reference to a custom object called `errorHandlerManager` that basically keeps a mapping between error type and error handler function. When the decorated function throws an error of a given type, the handler function associated with this type is invoked.

```js
function handleErrors(errorHandlerManager: IErrorHandlerManager) {
   return (target: any, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
      const fn = descriptor.value;
      descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fn.apply(this, args)
               .then((result: any) => {
                  resolve(result);
               })
               .catch((err: Error) => {
                  let handler = errorHandlerManager.getHandler(err.constructor.name);
                  if (typeof handler === 'function') {
                     handler();
                  } else {
                     reject(err);
                  }
               });
         });
      }
   };
}

// ...

@handleErrors(errorHandlerManager)
async loadData() {
   // Do something that might throw an error
}
```

My question is what should be a proper name for this decorator? I was thinking about `errorHandler` but it sounds kind of confusing as one might think the error handler is the decorated function. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As you mentioned yourself in the description, it is essentially a mapping operation, so how about @mapErrors?

Cool idea, by the way.